# The 'This' keyword in a form onsubmit call

Tags: javascript

I have been searching for an answer to this question for some time now, with no luck. It may be an easy one for some of you to answer.

In this tag:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="jcart" id="somethinghere" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
```

what does the 'this' keyword represent?

For example, if I wanted to call the 'validate' function on this form from inside another javascript function, how would I do it?

I know it is like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function MyTest(){
validate(???);
}
</script>
```

but I don't know what I should put inside the call to the validate function.

**EDIT**

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a form that is submitted via Ajax. It also has some validation on it as well. However, the validation script is usually called when the form is submitted. However, the Ajax function already gets the 'click' of the submit button and submits the data, so the form is never 'submitted' in a way to trigger the validation.

I have found this piece of code, which is responsible for submitting the form via Ajax.

```
    $('.jcart').submit(function(e) {
        add($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

So, I want to be able to run the validation function from there, and only call the add() function if the validation passes. But I don't know how to call the function from here, because I don't know how to reference the form to get the same element reference as the 'this' in the onsubmit call.

**EDIT 2**

I tried this:

```
$('.jcart').submit(function(e) {
    if(validate(document.getElementById("somethinghere"))){
        alert("validated");
        add($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        alert("not validated");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

but I get a 'validate is not defined' error.

Also, the code above is loaded at the end of the document, and the file with the validate function is called at the beginning. So I would have thought that the validate function would be available when I try to call it here, because it should be loaded already.

Comment: The code you found depends on jQuery it seems so u need to load jQuery... `validate` is not defined because it is not, I mean you don't have a `validate` function defined anywhere.

Comment: I have jQuery loaded already, at the top of the page. Also, the validate function is in an external JS file that is included in the header of the page. The jQuery code that I am using to try to call the validate function is included at the bottom of the page, before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that situation `this` represents the element the event occurred for, i.e., for the form element.

If you want to call `validate()` from somewhere else but have it validate that *same* form then just get a reference to the form with `.getElementByid()` and pass that:

```
function MyTest(){
  validate(document.getElementById("somethinghere"));
}
```

(Where "somethinghere" is your form's id.)

EDIT: Regarding *your* edits:

> *"I have found this piece of code, which is responsible for submitting the form via Ajax."*

```
    $('.jcart').submit(function(e) {
        add($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Are you *sure* that is responsible for submitting the form via Ajax? It would appear to be creating a submit handler on a form with the class "jcart", and the form you showed initially doesn't have that class. Unless the `add()` function that you don't show submits the "somethinghere" form?

> *"but I get a 'validate is not defined' error."*

If the inline `submit="return validate(this);"` works *on the same page* then `validate()` would have to be a global function so you could call it from anywhere on the page. If this doesn't work there must be more going on with your code than you've shown.

Comment: I fixed my original code, the form does have the class 'jcart'. The 'add' function is what submits the data.I'm not sure about the function not defined error. The validation code is called in the header of the page, and is normally called by the onsubmit method. The jQuery code I posted, which submits the form data, is included at the bottom of the page, right before the closing body tag. I'm not sure how to debug an error like this.

Comment: Within your jQuery `$(".jcart").submit()` handler `this` will represent the ".jcart" form so if that's the _same_ form you originally asked about you don't need `getElementById()` or anything. But in any case your "validate is not defined" error wouldn't have anything to do with what parameters you try to pass to it when you call it.

Comment: The .jcart class actually refers to a few different forms on the page. The jQuery code is called when any of the forms with that class are submitted. I am just trying to get the validation working on one of the forms first, and then can get the proper variables and stuff passed in. So there is a form with the ID 'somethinghere' as well.